# Android Studio - Sum of one column from Listadapter

Tags: java, listview, android-studio, listadapter

I made a Threecolumn listadapter. 
In my *`activity_main`* there is a *TextView*. This *`TextView`* should display a sum of all numbers from the third column of the `listview`.

I have like literally no idea how to include this. I tried to code it like a calculator but it gives me errors with `int`

heres some code:

This textview should show the sum

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etbetrag"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etbetrag"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etbetrag"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etbetrag"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnView"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Gesamte Ausgaben"
        android:textSize="45dp" />
```

of all

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etbetrag"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etausgabe"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="Betrag"
        android:inputType="number"/>
```

which are added to an threecolumn listadapter

best regards
yannick

Comment: Show us some code. Also, use \``` wrapped around your word rather than * around words when they're related to primitive types or objects, e.g. ```TextView``` vs *TextView*, ```int``` vs *int*

Comment: sorry about that, I am quiet new here

Comment: no problem. just letting you know of the markdown options SO has. They're very useful.

Comment: alright, I updated the question